# Rails 4: Not able to require Bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, rubygems, asset-pipeline

I am following Tuts+ tutorial on "Building a Polling Application in Rails". I have followed along with every foundational step to configure the app.

With the 'bootsrap-sass' gem installed, he simply adds the `*= require bootstrap` to the *application.css* file and instantly sees the changed results on his server. However, I receive the following error..

**localhost:3000**

```
Sprockets::FileNotFound in Polls#index
couldn't find file 'bootstrap'
(in /RAILS/tutspolls/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css:13)

Extracted source (around line #5):

  <html>
  <head>
    3 <title>Tutspolls</title>
     4 <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
     5 <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
     6 <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  </head>
```

This is what my files are looking like..

**Gemfile.rb**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


gem 'rails', '4.1.6'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.5'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'haml-rails'
gem 'pry-rails'

gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

gem 'spring',        group: :development

group :test do 
    gem 'factory_girl_rails'
    gem 'minitest-rails'
end
```

**stylesheets/application.css**

```
*= require bootstrap
*= require_tree .
*= require_self
*/
```

..and this was added to **config/application.rb**

```
config.sass.preferred_syntax = :sass
```

Through a google search as well as similar questions on Stackoverflow, I find similar issues with answers that are not working for me. My guess is that other it's a version issue or simply my lack of understanding between the asset pipeline and gem architecture.

Comment: Did you restart application server? also bootstrap should be required after require_tree and  require_self.

Comment: Yes, I have restarted the server many times. I just tried switching the *require bootstrap* after require tree and self but still see the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking over the versions of Bootstrap, I realized the tutorial is slightly older, so I switched from the defaulted `bootstrap-sass` which is version `'~> 3.2.0'` to `~> 3.1.1` and it works great.

Apparently the latest version of bootstrap-sass does not support `*= require bootstrap` and rather uses the `@import` which is current in the readme file. With the earlier version, I do not need to use `@import 'bootstrap-sprockets' when utilizing`*=`.

Answer (score 1):

According to [readme](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass#readme) you need:

1) Remove old `application.css` and create `application.css.scss`

2) In new `application.css.scss` include this lines:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

and `@import "bootstrap-sprockets"` **must** be imported before `@import "bootstrap"`.

I see that you mentioned `stylesheets/application.rb` file. What's this? Why do you use `sass` syntax in `.rb` file? Why do you use `*=` instead of `@import`? Where's importing of `bootstrap-sprockets`? Why do you skip it?

Comment: Thanks for the response and catching the incorrect file extension on my post, I updated it. The tutorial I am following uses `*=` and it works fine for him. I found the solution and will post it as an answer.

Comment: Guess you'll write about `bootstrap-sprockets`. I mentioned this mistake in my answer.